# How to check the Microsoft Outlook functionality using C Sharp in selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Scenario is like follows:

After clicking on a `email` link in application, `Outlook email` window is opened. I have to verify that the `To email` is present in the Outlook email window after clicking on email link from application and the rest of the outlook fields should be blank. I want to check this in `selenium webdriver` using C#. How can I do?

Comment: Is this just an `a` element with `mailto` inside it? If so you are testing browser functionality here. You aren't testing your application. You should just verify the `a` link has the correct details within the `href`.

Answer (score 0):

The case you have mentioned is out of scope and boundaries of Selenium. Once you click on the email link using Selenium, you will need to use a native UI automation testing tool like 
[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)